# Not able to get filename when picking file from Gdrive using file picker in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pick a file from Gdrive using filepicker.js and below method in javascript,but getting file.title is undefined. How to get the selected file name?. I need to read the data from the selected file.
Please help me.
    var picker = new FilePicker({

```
    apiKey:'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    clientId:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',       
    buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
    onSelect: function(file) {
        setTimeout("window.close()", 5000);
        fname=file.title;
        alert(fname)
        document.getElementById('filename').value=fname; 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of closing window before to get file name. Try this and may help you.

```
<script>
    function initPicker() {
        var picker = new FilePicker({
            apiKey: 'PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
            clientId: PUT_YOUR_NUMERIC_CLIENT_ID_HERE,
            buttonEl: document.getElementById('pick'),
            onSelect: function(file) {
                fname=file.title;
                alert(fname)
                document.getElementById('filename').value=fname; 
                setTimeout("window.close()", 5000);
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even though I remove the setTimeout("window.close()", 5000); facing same issue. Do I need to do any changes in filepicker.js?.